# About $(a,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

We know that every nonempty open subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals. I would like to see if how are we going to apply this result to the set $(a,+\infty)$, as this set is clearly open with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Meaning, how are we going to write $(a,+\infty)$ as a partition of open intervals? I tried but can't find one except to the the trivial(equating $(a,+\infty)$ to itself).

Comment: The only way to write an open interval (be it of the form $(-\infty,a)$, $(a,b)$, $(b,\infty)$, or $\mathbb R=(-\infty,\infty)$) as a disjoint union of open intervals is the trivial one.

Comment: The topological reason is that open intervals are connected.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo, so we can call(for the benefit of the result I stated) that the infinite intervals you listed are open intervals?

Comment: @jun: Yes, those are open intervals, too.  Fortunately this terminology all makes sense:  Under the definition of *open* as in open subset of $\mathbb R$, open intervals are open.  The fact that all open sets that are also intervals fall into one of the types Andres listed is not hard to show (using the least upper bound property).

Comment: @Jonas Meyer, thanks. I was not aware that the infinite intervals listed by Andres are open intervals.:)

Comment: What in the statement of the result you cite made you feel that you needed another expression as countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals, after having found the trivial one? Actually one could (and probably should) insert "uniquely" into the statement, and it would still be true. (And to compensate for the added length you could remove "nonempty", since one can take an empty union to make the empty set. The letter $G$ can also be removed.)

Comment: @Marc, noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little more to the theorem you are citing, it says:

- Every open subset of $\mathbb R$ can be written **uniquely** as a countable union of open intervals.

So a single open interval can't be broken up into a union of countably many smaller open intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to see that the proposed task is going to be impossible: Pick a bounded open subinterval $ (a,b) $ of $ (a,\infty) $. What other open subinterval of $ (a,\infty) $ can you pick to cover the point $ b $ while ensuring that there is no overlap with $ (a,b) $?

Comment: There is no such subinterval.:)

Comment: Yes. Hence, the only such partition consists of $ (a,\infty) $ itself. :)